# Unity 3D Quaternion Rotations: Help me to avoid Gimbal lock and make a smoth rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I'm currently working on a mobile game, it's a fairly simple core mechanic, you start with a single 3D cube and each turn you are given a new one that needs to be put or snapped to a face of a cube in the scene. You can select different faces of the cubes on the scene and the preview cube will spawn near that face so you can rotate it and find your desired placement. When you are happy with your choice just tap the "build cube button" the preview cube will disappear and the new one with the same values and rotation will appear on the selected face.
I just need to rotate an object around a selected Axis 90 or -90 degrees. That its, but it is useless hehe, please if someone could help me it will be a lot, this is bothering me for days now. Thanks!

```c#
public class CubeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Movement _movement;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!GetComponent<Movement>())
            Debug.LogWarning("Please add a movement script to the gameobject.");

        _movement = GetComponent<Movement>();
    }

    public void Move(Vector3[] positions, Action callBack)
    {
        _movement.StartMove(positions,callBack);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Rotate X Positive")]
    public void RotateAround_xAxisPositive()
    {
        Rotate(RotationAxis.X, true);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Rotate X Negative")]
    public void RotateAround_xAxisNegative()
    {
        Rotate(RotationAxis.X, false);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Rotate Y Positive")]
    public void RotateAround_yAxisPositive()
    {
        Rotate(RotationAxis.Y, true);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Rotate Y Negative")]
    public void RotateAround_yAxisNegative()
    {
        Rotate(RotationAxis.Y, false);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Rotate Z Positive")]
    public void RotateAround_zAxisPositive()
    {
        Rotate(RotationAxis.Z, true);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Rotate Z Negative")]
    public void RotateAround_zAxisNegative()
    {
        Rotate(RotationAxis.Z, false);
    }

    public void Rotate(RotationAxis axis, bool positiveRotation)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoRotation(axis,90, positiveRotation));
    }

    IEnumerator DoRotation(RotationAxis axis,float angles, bool positiveRotation)
    {
        float time = 1;
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Quaternion destinationRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        Vector3 anglesToRotate = Vector3.zero;

        switch (axis)
        {
            case RotationAxis.X:
                if (positiveRotation)
                    anglesToRotate = new Vector3(90, 0, 0);
                else
                    anglesToRotate = new Vector3(-90, 0, 0);
                break;
            case RotationAxis.Y:
                if (positiveRotation)
                    anglesToRotate = new Vector3(0, 90, 0);
                else
                    anglesToRotate = new Vector3(0, -90, 0);
                break;
            case RotationAxis.Z:
                if (positiveRotation)
                    anglesToRotate = new Vector3(0, 0, 90);
                else
                    anglesToRotate = new Vector3(0, 0, -90);
                break;
            default:
                Debug.LogError("You must assign a rotation axis!");
                break;
        }
        destinationRotation *= this.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(anglesToRotate);

        Quaternion yRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        Quaternion xRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        Quaternion zRotation = Quaternion.identity;


        while (elapsedTime < time)
        {
            yRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(anglesToRotate.y * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up);
            xRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(anglesToRotate.x * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.right);
            zRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(anglesToRotate.z * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.forward);

            this.transform.rotation = yRotation * xRotation * zRotation * this.transform.rotation;

            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        //this.transform.rotation = yRotation * xRotation * zRotation;
        //this.transform.rotation = destinationRotation;
    }
}

public enum RotationAxis
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
}
```

Comment: Using euler angles is the source of your gimbal lock and you don't need to use them.  You can derive the destination rotation quaternions from the transform.up, transform.forward, etc of the cube you are snapping to by using Quaterion.LookAt.  Once you have the start and destination quaternions, you can slerp from one to the other.

Comment: How will you prevent multiple concurrent coroutines are running at the same time?

Comment: Okay, so. First i know that by using Euler I will run on to Gimbal Lock. But i dont fully understand Quaternions  XD...
Can you expand on " You can derive the destination rotation quaternions from the transform.up, transform.forward, etc of the cube you are snapping to by using Quaterion.LookAt."

Comment: And about the Coroutines, yes, you are right.  But the script wasn't finished yet, and I didn't stop on that stuff.  I'll take care of it, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never supposed to set rotation like this, it will simply not work and the Unity docs warn about it as well.

```
this.transform.rotation = yRotation * xRotation * zRotation * this.transform.rotation;
```

If you are rotating one axis at a time you can use.

```
transform.Rotate(90.0f ,0.0f,0.0f,Space.World);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

You can also use LookAt

```
transform.LookAt(targetCube);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

You can also use Quaternion.Lerp

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html

In general rotations in Unity can be tricky, especially if they are seemingly easy in the inspector.

Comment: hehe thank you for answering me. I'm pretty new to C# and Unity so, this is a little overwhelming topic.
1. Okay, so i should not make rotations like that ever again! hehe.
2. I tried transform.Rotate(90.0f ,0.0f,0.0f,Space.World); but it dident work for me, i dont exactly know why, i need to rotate on the 3 axis on demand, not at the same time, but when ever the player needs it.
3. I tried Quaternion.Lerp and i run on to Gimbal Lock anyway. What can I do!!!
I will add another script that i test but i didn't work. After a couple of rotations on the different axis it runs into a gimbal lock

Comment: Also, I need to rotate exactly 90 degrees, no more, no less. :S

Comment: if you can make the rotations exactly and record them as Quaternion and then lerp or switch between Quaternion this is your best bet, you cant tell Quaternions to rotate 90 degrees in code though however if you had the cubes rotated somewhere in the scene you could copy the quaternion of the rotation you need if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestROtate : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] float duration = 1; // seconds, must be >0.0f
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.identity;

[ContextMenu("Rotate X Positive")]
public void RotateAround_xAxisPositive()
{
    targetRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);
    StopAllCoroutines();
    StartCoroutine(DoRotation());
}

[ContextMenu("Rotate Y Positive")]
public void RotateAround_yAxisPositive()
{
    targetRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
    StopAllCoroutines();
    StartCoroutine(DoRotation());
}

[ContextMenu("Rotate Z Positive")]
public void RotateAround_zAxisPositive()
{
    targetRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
    StopAllCoroutines();
    StartCoroutine(DoRotation());
}


// other rotate methods

IEnumerator DoRotation()
{
    float currentTime = 0;
    Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;

    while (currentTime < 1)
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime / duration;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, targetRotation, 
 currentTime);

            yield return null;
        }
        transform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }
 }
```